# Limitation of speed of data transfer between two external HDs on the same USB port

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I have the following itens:

- MacBook Air M1 (with 2 USB-C 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10Gb/s))
- 2 identical external hard drivers with 2TB and USB-A 3.0
- USB adapter/dongle USB-A 3.0 to USB-C 3.0

My questions are:

1. If I connect both external HDs on the same USB adapter (plugged on
   only one USB-C on my Mac) and transfer data between them, will I
   compromise the data transfer speed?
2. If I buy a new USB-A to USB-C adapter and connect each external HD
   on separated USB ports, will I increase the data transfer speed
   between those external HDs?

Comment: Are the drives externally powered? Or the adapter?

Comment: @jaskij no, both use just the USB port to get power

Comment: In that case, I'd connect them to separate ports. I'm not sure how much power the MacBook can provide on USB, but HDDs are generally power hungry, especially 3.5" 7200 RPM ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

External HDD drives peak anywhere between 60MB/s and 150MB/s depending on the type (2.5" or 3.5"), drive quality and manufacturer. A cheap external 2.5" drive would manage the low end of that, while a high quality 3.5" drive would manage 150MB/s.

150MB/s (megabytes per second) is in the ballpark of 1200Mbps (megabits per second) or 1.2Gbps. To go from bytes per second to bits per second you simply multiply by 8.

On a 10Gbps link you *should* be completely fine transferring from one HDD to another. 2 x 1.2 = 2.4. Which is less than 10.

If the external drives are SSDs then the story is slightly different.

A SATA SSD can manage 500MB/s, while an NVMe one could manage anywhere from 2GBps (note the capital B for bytes instead of bits) up to 7GBps.

500MB/s would be 4Gbps, so in theory two external SATA SSD drives could just about be okay on one 10Gbps port, but you may start hitting protocol overheads causing some slow down.

An external NVMe drive at 2GBps would be 16Gbps so even one of those would saturate a 10Gbps port and would not operate at peak speed.

To summarise.

For HDDs you likely will have no problem and will not even be close to maximum port speeds.

For SSDs you will likely be limited to around 500 to 600MB/s between the drives.

The answer to number 2 depends entirely on the internals of yout laptop. If the bandwidth to the USB C ports is shared or not, that is not something that can be guessed and would be better for you to test.

If you get about 1 gigabyte per second copy speeds from one drive to a second when using multiple ports then your bandwidth is not shared and each port is separate.

Comment: Nitpick: The numbers are actually lower than this, both because of encoding overhead (which drops effective USB 3.0 bandwidth from the theoretical 625 MB/s (5 Gb/s times 8) to about 500 MB/s), and because of protocol overhead (which depends on whether USB MSC or UAS is being used for the transfer, and how good the hub is). In practice, this does not matter for the case of two traditional hard drives, but it means that transferring between two SSDs will actually be even slower (based on experience, typically not even 400 MB/s using UAS and a good hub).